# Use setState in SetTimout() in render function

Tags: reactjs

```
render() {
      ...
      if (changed) {

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({book_id: book.id});
          })
      }


}
```

If no setTimeout, there will be console warning. There is enough reason to update state based on logic. My question is

1) Is this pattern against or comply with best practice?

2)Why?

Comment: Why do you want to do setTimeout?

Comment: To update state in the component

Comment: but why do you need it to be asynchronous ?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case. What's `changed` and why is it in render? It's unclear what you're trying to do. setState shouldn't appear in render.

Comment: The right way is using componentDidUpdate to make async actions including setState after timeout

Comment: I thinks you setState everywhere, but not in render function.

Comment: @ArtemKolodko why?

Comment: @estus, OP is trying to set state from render and asks if this is a bad practice and why. I don't know what's so unclear about that question

Comment: @SanderGarretsen Because this depends on where `change` comes from. It's possible that there are circumstances under which this can be considered undesirable but acceptable hack (e.g. context API). Users don't have to guess about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `setState` in render, it will rerender the component and will call `setState` again and you have just created a infinite loop.

Here you can read about React Life Cycles https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/the_life_cycle_recap.html

There you can see an image where it is ok to `setState`;

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As **Modig** said, using **setState** inside render() will create an infinite loop. which is something to be avoided generally.

**Moreover** about the Why? you can check

> https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

which is a very decent and quite up-to-date style guide for js/jsx as you will see inside the **best practices** you asked for.

**Finally**, depending also on the text-editor/IDE you might be using there is a way to import their .eslint so it can show you warning while writting code when you dont use a best practice or when you have to avoid something.